# read only particular fields in two csv files and compare whethere they are identical or not identical in php

Tags: php

I have two csv files both files have same content ,for example one file have name, pin code and another file also have name and pin code but I want to read in both files particular name contents not pin code contents and give output whether they are identical or not identical in PHP

file1
name  pin code 
USA      67301 
INDIA    67301
KOREA    67301

file2
name  pin code 
USA      67301 
INDIA    67301
KOREA    67301

````
define('READ_LEN', 4096);
if(files_ identical('file1.csv', 'file2.csv'))
    echo 'files identical';
else
    echo 'files not identical';


function files_ identical($fn1, $fn2) {
    if(filetype($fn1) !== filetype($fn2))
        return FALSE;

    if(file size($fn1) !== file size($fn2))
        return FALSE;
    if(!$fp1 = f open($fn1, 'r b'))
        return FALSE;
        if(!$fp2 = f open($fn2, 'r b')) {
        f close ($fp1);
        return FALSE;
    }

    $same = TRUE;
    while (!f e o f($fp1) and !f e of($fp2))
        if( f read ($fp1, READ_LEN) !== f read ($fp2, READ_LEN)) {
            $same = FALSE;
            break;
        }

    if(f e of($fp1) !== f e o f($fp2))
        $same = FALSE;
    f close($fp1);
    f close($fp2);
    return $same;}
?>```


the above file I read the entire file I show whether they are identical or non identical but how to show particular fields in both files like name contents has to be read and display the whether they are same or not
````

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question lacks of a reproducable piece of code. Show us, what you 've tried so far. Further show us the structure of your CSV (at least a reproducable example). Stack Overflow is not a service to find someone who does your job.

Comment: I tried to read entire file but how to read particular filed like particular name contents in both file whether they are same or not